# Using Wine in Heroku

Tags: linux, heroku, wine

Can anybody help me figure out how do I use Wine in Heroku?
I deployed Wine to Heroku with the button in the readme of https://github.com/TheBotlyNoob/heroku-buildpack-wine.
But when I tried to run Wine like this:
[image: Trying to run Wine in Heroku]

It didn't work. Am I trying to run Wine wrong? Or is there another step I need to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed both versions of wine (*stable and release*) but when I try to execute the command on the bash the shell answer that the file doesn't exist:

```
bash: /app/vendor/wine/bin/wine: No such file or directory
```

[Heroku bash: wine not such file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBu1E.jpg)

Even if wine is installed and the file is executable:

[wine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBu1E.jpg)

If you try to launch notepad the answer of the bash is the same:

```
/app/vendor/wine/bin/notepad: 46: exec: /app/vendor/wine/bin/wine: not found
```

even if wine is in the PATH.

**Conclusion**: wine doesn't execute.
A way to have wine on Heroku is to download the package from ubuntu with his dependencies, put them in the repository and install it.
Hope it was useful.